# Dual Slope integrator voltmeter improvement in Design

Tags: adc, avr, voltmeter, dual

So, I'm attempting to design a dual-slope integrator voltmeter. I have the following block diagram so far.

[image]

Now an AVR microcontroller will have an ADC pin in the range of 0-5 Volts . So negative voltage would have to be conditioned somehow and then the software section will be used to translate and interpret it.
Are there any suggestions and improvements you can make to this general scheme? Is there an alternative to the dual slope integrator section? Suppose the range is a modest -5 V to 5 V for example.

Okay, I want to accomplish something like this but with dual slope integration and the ability to detect negative polarity:
[image]

Comment: Might want to include schematics.

Comment: How about I just try to explain each section.

Comment: Most people here want to see schematics, you can draw them with the tool.

Comment: A dual-slope voltmeter is essentially a ratiometric voltage to time converter. If you're planning on  using SAR ADC somehow you really need to explain that in some detail to get useful suggestions. The most succinct and precise way to explain things is via a schematic and timing diagrams. Getting a dual-slope ADC to work for bipolar inputs may involve a few more analog switches or something more.

Comment: Am most curious about the **AVR ADC pin block**. Conventional integrating voltmeters use a *comparator*, along with clock & counters, not an *ADC*. Am unsure what you're planning.

Comment: I haven't gotten to schematics yet. But I want to read a voltage, remove noise from it using dual-slope integration (?) and then send that to a microcontroller's ADC pin and then display the correct reading either on an LCD or a serial terminal/console.

Comment: Okay, I edited my question. Hopefully there is some clarity now. There's also a schematic of a simulation I just ran. (credit to circuit digest ofcourse)

Comment: Some ADC design questions: How much dynamic range (largest measurement)? How much resolution (smallest detail)? How many samples per second are required? Should it reject 50Hz or 60Hz power line frequency? Do you know the source impedance of the sensor being measured by the ADC? Is there constraint on size, cost, load current?

Comment: How about -5V to 5V. Just DC measurements,

Comment: @glen_geek *Conventional integrating voltmeters use a comparator* Yes, but if you got an MCU with a reasonable ADC, using the comparator is a premature pessimization. Much better performance is possible by using even an 8-bit ADC instead. That's the technique used by many high-performance multi-slope voltmeters, including the stalwart standard: HP 3458A.

Answer (score 2):

If I was asked to draw it using mostly rectangles, here's how I'd approach it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCVs4u.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- IQ: current sources
- SW: current switch
- INT: integrator
- CTL: comparator or ADC used to control the switches
- VREF: voltage or current reference

The input protection and attenuation would be connected to the input terminals of this block diagram. How far does the "analog front-end" extend is hard to say. You could, for example, consider everything up to IQ to be the analog front-end.

Here is how such a dual-slope integrator may be actually implemented:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpTQo4.png)</sup>

The basic building blocks are:

1. Current sources / slope generators.
2. Current switches.
3. Integrator.
4. Comparator / ADC & switch control.
5. Bootstrap voltage buffer.

The bootstrap buffer improves performance, since the switches always "see" the same potential no matter which way they are switched.

The switches direct the currents from the current sources either to the integrator, or to the "dump" node at the output of the bootstrap buffer.

The "comparator" performs much better if it's an ADC. A comparator would be a 1-bit ADC. But we can use more bits if we got them!

High-precision integrating bench multimeters use this approach. The ADC lets one interpolate higher resolution time value for when the integrator output crossed a threshold.

At the simplest, the software waits until the analog input is between say 10% and 90% of the input range. Then it collects the data as the input ramps through that range. Then it does a linear fit of the data, and determines the time when the line crossed the threshold. This time has a much better resolution than the sampling period of the ADC! And, together with an integrator, you get a "hybrid" voltmeter that may have resolution and accuracy orders of magnitude better than the ADC on the microcontroller.

---

Now we'd like to implement this thing using a single 5V supply, and a 0..5V range ADC in an MCU. The circuit has to use rail-to-rail op-amps.

First, the three current sources:

- -25μA...-225μA proportional to input voltage
- -250μA fixed
- +500μA fixed

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXQSJE.png)</sup>

Now we can plug those into a switch, add an integrator and an ADC:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f66yxm.png)</sup>

SW1-SW6 can be 3/3 of a 74HC4053, or 6/8 of a 74HC4066.

With average integrator current of 0.25mA, 5Hz sampling rate, and ±1.5V integrator output swing, the integrating capacitance
$$
C = \frac{Q}{U} = \frac{I\cdot T}{U}
= \frac{0.25{\,\rm mA}\cdot 1/(5{\,\rm Hz})}{1.5{\,\rm V}}
\approx 33{\,\rm\mu F}.
$$

There are of course plenty of improvements possible to this circuit, but I'd expect it to work as-shown. All of the op-amps can have GBW between 1MHz and 5MHz and I'd expect them to need no additional compensation.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://microdigisoft.com/single-slope-and-dual-slope-adc-analog-to-digital-converter/) and [this](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ICL7106-ICL7107.pdf).

Here is an [example](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/h3jsuwafc17n4i5b4919t/dual-slope-voltmeter-031.CIR?rlkey=ah4pfvr6nqdssyg2ui5yvnray&dl=0) (made with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110)) of "analog" front end,
and a "digital" counter back end of a 3 1/2 digits dual slope, dual polarity.

The digital counter part can be made with a MCU.

V1, V2, V3 should be the results.
V1 < 0 ... should read : count1 -"2000" -> V1 shown as negative voltage.
V2 = 0 ... should read : count2 (= 2000) - "2000" -> V2 = 0.
V3 > 0 ... should read : count3- "2000"  -> V3 shown as positive voltage .
Just change R1, R2,C1.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]